# Rails: Confirming two objects were saved at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationships

When a user is created on my site I want a User.new instance to execute but I also need to make a Alias.new object too. Users have many Aliases. However, I also need to validate that there are no other Aliases with that name before saving.

From the console my code might look like this:

```
u = User.new(:name => "Bob")
a = Alias.new(:name => "SirBob", :user_id => u)
```

But that's doesn't work since u doesn't have a id until I save. So how do I validate both items for uniqueness of name before saving them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
u = User.new  
u.aliases.build
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This allows me to create them all at once. But I can't figure out how to validate the aliases requirements... I'm able to create Aliases that should be failing.

Comment: This works but I had to edit my User model to include this:
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :aliases
validates_associated :alias`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  u = User.new(:name => "Bob")
  a = Alias.new(:name => "SirBob", :user_id => u)
end
```

and add `validates_uniqueness_of :name` on Alias model

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is with this. I get crazy errors like this:

`Expected /var/www/ror/email/app/models/alias.rb to define Alias`